How to do full drive/bare-metal-restore backup of Intel iMac with Bootcamp partition 2024
Need a bulletproof tool to do full drive/bare-metal-restore backup of Intel iMac with Bootcamp partition.
TwoCanoes comes to mind but lack of documentation on how-to scenarios (or at least I couldn't find any) make me wary.
The Windows partition contains a ton of LOB apps that are no longer available for re-install/activation (legacy/unsupported) so failure is not an option situation.
Windows is finicky about Office and others being on a new drive - licenses matched to hardware ID's.  Are these cloned in the restore?
Bonus question: what format should the removable SSD drive for the backup be, APFS, exFAT?
Advice?

It's been a long time since I needed to do this but I believe that "Winclone" will do the Windows partition and CCC/Superduper will do the same for the Mac side. I'm not aware of any tool that will do both Mac/BootCamp partitions. Unless you are a an expert, of sorts, in disk partitioning I would stay away from utilities such as GPartED. We regularly get people who end up munging their disks using unfamiliar tools.

What macOS? IF Catalina or earlier you can try Bombich's Carbon Copy Cloner (v6), even in free Trial mode it made me a bootable external copy on SSD drive. So you could give that a try regarding what hardware is seen and matched for licences... CCC would make APFS where required, their website has a lot of great information.

Nope, Carbon Copy Cloner wont do what I asked about.
From https://bombich.com/en/kb/ccc/5/can-ccc-back-up-my-bootcamp-windows-partition
"Will CCC clone both my macOS and Windows partition at the same time?
No, CCC will copy only one volume at a time, and CCC will not modify the partitioning of the destination disk. You should apply your custom partitioning prior to restoring anything to your new disk."
